# sentiWordNet in rapidminer

Tags: sentiment-analysis, rapidminer, senti-wordnet

I am trying to integrate SentiWordNet into Rapidminer using the Extract Sentiment operator. I cannot find a way to get the dictionary input, in fact even if I use the OpenWordnetDictionary operator I get "Map failed" error.
Has anyone of you ever (successfully) performed the same operation or know how I can make it work?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some examples [here](http://rapid-i.com/rapidforum/index.php/topic,6035.0.html). The basic trick is to put the Sentiword text file into the same folder as the Wordnet dictionary.

Comment: thank you for your replay, I managed to make it work this way!

Comment: Perhaps you could up-vote the answer to show it's useful.